# Subscribe to actions on keyboard (press key)

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, 
I want to receive messages in ROS that tell me which key was pressed on a keyboard that is connected with the PC. I found several examples for other input devices and also some of them treated the keyboard but just with the up and down arrows. Could you tell me if there is a way to receive also messages when the other keys were pressed (like a letter)? Are there preinstalled nodes/programmes?

 
With best regards,
Rick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295940/subscribe-to-actions-on-keyboard-(press-key)/) by [Rick](https://answers.ros.org/users/36114/rick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2018-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll want to write:

1. a keyboard publisher node that publishes key-presses as strings

   - e.g. this one: https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_twist_keyboard/blob/master/teleop_twist_keyboard.py
2. a subscriber node that subscribes to the key-presses topic.

*(or you could handle it all in one script, but this is a more elegant approach)*

---

Also, see these related answers: https://answers.ros.org/question/63491/keyboard-key-pressed/

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) with karma: 697 on 2018-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick](https://answers.ros.org/users/36114/rick/) on 2018-07-03**:
Ok, thank you for your answer.